# Float and double precision in C

Tags: c, precision

In C, double has more precision than float, and according to "C primerplus sixth edition" book (page 80), a float can represent at least 6 significant figures and a double can represent at least 13 significant figures. So I tried to verify that with this simple example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    float a = 3.3333333; // 7 significant digits
    double b = 3.33333333333333;// 14 significant digits

    printf("\nFloat:  %f\n", a);
    printf("Double: %f\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output of this program:

```
Float : 3.333333
Double: 3.333333
```

Why does the double value have the same precision as the float value, instead of displaying more significant digits?

Comment: According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/, the default number of digits to print after the decimal point is 6.

Comment: See http://codepad.org/3XfCoo0s for example.

Comment: `3.3333333` has 8 significant digits, just like `33.333333`, `333.33333`, `3333.3333` etc. Thats how it works.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help

Comment: `double` (typically) *stores* more significant digits than `float`. `printf` doesn't *display* more significant digits unless you ask it to. (Incidentally, there's no language guarantee that `double` is wider than `float`; they could both have the same representation, as long as they satisfy the requirements for `double`.)

Comment: `double` has [**at least 10**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.2p11) significant decimal digits, not 13. Same for `long double` which can be identical to `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most questions like this can be answered by consulting the C standard:

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the '%' character ... after which the following appear in sequence:
>
> ...
>
> - An optional precision that gives ... the number of digits to appear after the radix character for the a, A, e, E, f, and F conversion specifiers.

Describing the `f` specifier:

> The double argument shall be converted to decimal notation in the style "[-]ddd.ddd", where the number of digits after the radix character is equal to the precision specification. **If the precision is missing, it shall be taken as 6**.

So, by simply using `%f`, you are instructing `printf` to print six digits after the `.`.  If you want to see more digits, you need to specify the precision: `%.15f`, for example.

Comment: Thank you man. I didn't know that, I'm new to C programming so...And if you can provide me with a link to the C standards, I'll be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to show more significant digits.  If you do this:

```
printf("\nFloat:  %.20f\n", a);
printf("Double: %.20f\n", b);
```

You'll get this:

```
Float:  3.33333325386047363281
Double: 3.33333333333332992865
```

Comment: Double precision has 53 bit mantissaa (leading 1 bit assumed, 52 bits stored), which is 16 digits (~ 15.9546 digits). The digits beyond that are related to the conversion to string (converting binary fractional to a decimal fractional).