# C++ double act as float?

Tags: c++, variables, floating-point, double, var

C++

```
float f = 0.123456789;
double d = 0.123456789;

cout << "float = " << f << endl;
cout << "double = " << d << endl;
```

Output

```
float = 0.123457
double = 0.123457
```

Why?
How to use *double* and *long double*?
Is there a variable larger than *long double*?

Comment: Read up on stream manipulators such as `std::setw` and `std::fixed`.

Comment: Number of digits in displayed floating point number is configured on the `std::cout` side and is not necessarily dependent on number of bytes representing that value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout

Comment: why what? Please explain what else you expected

Comment: duplicate in C: [Float and double precision in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32291052/995714)

Comment: My answer to another question may be of relevance:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968737/comparison-of-double-long-double-float-and-float128/50970282#50970282

Comment: @Eljay , That's a best answer, if you post it as answer, i well give you (best answer). thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is not exactly what the content of the variables is, but what the standard ouptut stream outputs after rounding them. Look up the [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) function from the header `<iomanip>`.

A quick test on Coliru with:

```
float f = 0.123456789;
double d = 0.123456789;

std::cout << "float = " << std::setprecision(13) << f << std::endl;
std::cout << "double = " << std::setprecision(13) << d << std::endl;
```

yields the output:

> float = 0.1234567910433
>
> double = 0.123456789

It shows that indeed, float and double are not the same type in terms of which numbers they can represent. (Hint: this is not even the exact number stored in the float, only the one rounded to 13 significant digits).

Comment: thank you, but 1- what is 10433 after 0.12345679 in float? 2- float 6 or 9 decimal?

Comment: I would suggest that you look up and learn more about the floating types themselves as your questions touch on a more general topic. As I mentioned in my question, they're not able to represent every single real number in an exact manner.