# Printing doubles with large precision with printf, compiling with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, printf, double, precision

When printing with printf in a C program and specify how much characters I want after the decimal point with `%.20f`, it only gives me 15 characters and the rest are 0. I compile with GCC with the command `gcc -o main main.c`  is there any flag I should add when compiling?

I have this simple program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double a = 233.12376886221625447234;

int main ()
{
    printf("a = %.20f\r\n",a);
    printf("a = %f\r\n",a);
}
```

and the output from it is

```
a = 233.12376886221625000000
a = 233.123769
```

I compile with the command `gcc -o main main.c`

Comment: Precision of Double is till 15 digits, and of float is till 7 digits i think, so you wont get accuracy beyond that

Comment: Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291052/float-and-double-precision-in-c out

Comment: Perhaps using ```long double``` variable and ```%Lf``` would help.

Comment: You may get more digits if  you use `long double` and `%Lf`, but there are limits to the number of digits you can get from a `double` (and, indeed, a `long double`).

Comment: @PaperPLane Well, that's not the issue here

Comment: Exact precision is implementation defined. Here https://ideone.com/l5drYy the precision is better (which seems more normal)

Answer (score 1):

`double` can *exactly* encode about 2<sup>64</sup> different finite values.  Usually `double` is a 64-bit obejct.

`233.12376886221625447234` is **not** one of them.

The 2 closest [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) are some integer times a power of 2 such as:

```
233.1237688622162_522733560763299465179443359375  // Closest
233.1237688622162_5447234  // OP's code
233.1237688622162_80695065506733953952789306640625 // Next higher
```

The better question is:  why the `double` 233.1237688622162_522733560763299465179443359375 was printed as `233.1237688622162_500000`?

```
// OP's output
//3 4567890123456 7890123
233.1237688622162_5000000
```

As OP's output produced the above simply reflects the implementation choice of how to present values with such high precision.

C does not specify, beyond a certain number of digits, what should be printed.  Appending zeros is allowed past a certain point.  OP did see `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` (17) *significant* digits which about minimally meets C requirements.   In other words, `"233.1237688622162_5000000"` is sufficient for many applications.

IIRC, [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) obliges `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 3` significant digits to be printed before simply appending zeros.  But then C does not require IEEE 754 compliance.

Let us conclude OP's implementation is somewhat weak.

Consider that printing floating point values (encoded using binary) precisely as decimal has limited usefulness beyond `DBL_DECIMAL_DIGIT` significant decimal digits.  Only select implementations will print `DBL_TRUE_MIN` [exactly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485) out to it full *exact* value - which may be 100s of characters.

---

Use `%a` instead to print the *exact* value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
  double a = 233.12376886221625447234;
  printf("%.50g\n", a);
  puts("233.12376886221625447234");
  printf("%.50g\n", nextafter(a,a*2));
  printf("%a\n", a);
}
```

Sample output

```
233.1237688622162522733560763299465179443359375
233.12376886221625447234
233.123768862216280695065506733953952789306640625
0x1.d23f5ea1def6cp+7
```

Comment: Which compiler did you use to output these numbers?

Comment: @KamenPetkov, some info:   GNU C11 (GCC) version 11.4.0 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)
 compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.2.0-p9, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.26-GMP

Comment: @KamenPetkov Why do you want more than 17 significant decimal digit precision?

Answer (score 0):

Use `long double` data type to print larger variables the format specifier is `%Lf`
[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfj6B.png)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eytQN.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Don't post links to images of simple code.  Embed the code as code in your answer.